# Highlight texts in a pdf file with background colour

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

Need a solution to highlight specific text with a background color in PDF and final result to be in the new pdf file.. I tried few solutions based on itextSharp but no luck as yet. Could you please help me with the solution.

```
private static void PDFTextGetter(string pSearch, StringComparison sc, string sourceFile, string destinationFile)
    {
        PdfStamper stamper;
        PdfContentByte cb;

        var pReader = new PdfReader(sourceFile);

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            stamper = new PdfStamper(pReader, fs);
            for (int page = 1; page <= pReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                var strategy = new myLocationTextExtractionStrategy();
                cb = stamper.GetUnderContent(page);
                strategy.UndercontentCharacterSpacing = cb.CharacterSpacing;
                strategy.UndercontentHorizontalScaling = cb.HorizontalScaling;


                string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pReader, page, strategy);


                List<iTextSharp.text.Rectangle> matchesFound = strategy.GetTextLocations(pSearch, sc);

                 cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.YELLOW);


                foreach (iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect in matchesFound)
                    cb.Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Bottom, rect.Width, rect.Height);

                cb.Fill();


            }
            stamper.Close();
            pReader.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its hard to help you fix the solutions you have tried when you don't include that code.

Comment: You talk about **iTextSharp**, but that name has been abandoned two year ago in favor of the name **iText for .NET**. Are you sure you have tried iText 7 and its add-ons? The algorithms behind the pdfSweep add-on are exactly what you need (except for the fact that pdfSweep also *removes* the content).

Comment: I have added the code block in the post. i have tried the same with iTextSharp from nuget and it was 5.1.xx release. I haven't tried it with iText7. Could you please review the code once. Thank you.

Comment: 5.1.xx is ancient. On nuget you get 5.5.xx versions.